# Check the sqlite database to decide the color of icons

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter

I have a database where I store the ids of favorite articles and i created a function to check if the Id exist in the table Favoris here it is :

```
existFavoris(int idArticle) async{
    final db = await database;

    var res =await db.query("Favoris", where: "idArticle = ?", whereArgs: [idArticle]);
    return res.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

I created a button to add/remove the id from the table

```
StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState){
            return new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.star, 
                color: decideColor(idArticle) 
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                if(DBProvider.db.existFavoris(idArticle)){
                  DBProvider.db.removeFromFavoris(idArticle);
                }
                else {
                  DBProvider.db.addToFavoris(idArticle);
                }
              },
            );
          },
```

Here is the decideColor() code that checks if id exists in DB:

```
decideColor(int idArticle){
if (DBProvider.db.existFavoris(idArticle)){
  return Color(0xffffD700);
}
return Colors.white;
```

}

I keep getting this error:

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

Comment: Does `DBProvider.db.existFavoris(idArticle)` return a bool?

Comment: Yes the isNotEmpty property is bool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your `existFavoris` is async, then it at least returns Future. You have to await the response from that function.

---

Make `onPressed` async and await `existFavoris`

```
onPressed: () async {
    var exists = await DBProvider.db.existFavoris(idArticle);
    if(exists){
       DBProvider.db.removeFromFavoris(idArticle);
    } else {
       DBProvider.db.addToFavoris(idArticle);
    }
},
```